# how to transfer file between two RPI over Wi-fi?

Tags: wifi, pi-4, data-transfer

Hello I received two Pi 4 for Christmas. It is the first time I use RPI, I have succeeded to turn them on and to connect them to my local wifi !

I am a a beginner  and I wanted to start with a simple project : connecting 2 RPI together and send data( file of 60 Mo) through Wi-fi between them.

After startup, an automatic connection is set up between the RPI[1] and the RPI[2],  RPI[1] sends a set of data to the RPI[2].

The idea would be that RPI [1] should send a "presence" signal only every 30 min approximatively (configurable)

The RPI[2] would be in permanent listening, and as soon as it receives the signal of presence of the RPI[1],
it opens a communication protocol with the RPI[2] of the type :
"I know that RPI[1] is there, RPI[1] confirms that it is sending me data, I receive the data,
I check the integrity of the data (how ..?), I confirm receipt to RPI[1], I close the communication".
"If the integrity of the data is not good, I ask for the data to be sent back from RPI[1] following the same process as before".

I was wondering :

- the simpliest way to send file through Wi-fi ?
- Which protocol to choose ? TCP or MQTT ( seemed better than http)
- which languages to choose ? Python or C ?
- Any good ressources to help me started or similar projects ?
- This is a good "scenario" ?

Thank you in advance for your help,
Antoine

Comment: I would read up on CRON for timing and RSYNC for sending files. MQTT is really designed for small (byte sized) messages rather than files.  Linux is a very mature operating system and often there is a tool already and often it's more important to lever existing tools than re-invent the world.

Comment: your question is not about a Raspberry Pi ... it is a question about Linux

Answer (score 4):

To answer your last point

> - This is a good "scenario" ?

and with the announcement

> I am a a beginner and I wanted to start with a simple project : connecting 2 RPI together and send data( file of 60 Mo) through Wi-fi between them.

I would say "No".

To transfer a file form **RPi1** to **RP2** just use:

```
rpi ~$ scp /path/to/file pi@rpi2:/path/to/file
```

To repeat this automatically after a time, create a systemd service with a timer:

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl edit --force --full transfer-file.service
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Unit]
Description=Transfer file
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/scp /path/to/file pi@rpi2:/path/to/file

rpi ~$ sudo systemctl edit --force --full transfer-file.timer
```

In the empty editor insert these statements, save them and quit the editor:

```
[Timer]
OnActiveSec=30min
```

Enable and manage this with

```
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl enable --now transfer-file.timer
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl status transfer-file.timer
rpi ~$ sudo systemctl edit --full transfer-file.timer
```

This will transfer a file every 30 minutes. All error handling and handshake is done by the operating system, the *scp* program and the TCP network protocol.

Comment: How can I manage the password issue between the two RPI ? I think this is the reason why it doesn't work. when using  "sudo systemctl enable --now transfer-file.timer" I get  sudo systemctl enable --now transfer-file.timer
The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy=, RequiredBy=, Also=,
Alias= settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance= for template
units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using systemctl.

Answer (score 2):

If this file transfer is to be an ongoing effort, you may wish to consider [`rsync`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rsync). If you're using the RPi OS, `rsync` is pre-installed, and you can learn about its use by perusing `man rsync`.

You have at least two choices for running `rsync` across two RPis:

1. set up an SSH connection
2. set up a Samba server(s) on one or both RPis & mount the shared drives

If you use the SSH connection, you may find it convenient to [set up a public-private key pair](https://www.discoverbits.in/post/how-to-set-up-rsync-to-transfer-files-between-servers-over-ssh/) as that will avoid userid+password authentication which can be messy and insecure.

All of the information you need to do this is [available online for the cost of an Internet search](https://duckduckgo.com/?t=ffnt&q=rsync+across+computers&ia=web). Please take a few minutes to read some of these search results. If you have *specific* questions, please post those as separate questions.